# Email sending in django code is not working

Tags: html, django, email

Email sending in django code is not working,
it display error "[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"
these are my **VIEWS.PY**

```
def send_email(request):
username = request.POST.get('username', '')
from_email = request.POST.get('from_email', '')
message = request.POST.get('message', '')
if username and message and from_email:
    try:
        send_mail(username, from_email, message,  ['canonizadocharm@ymail.com'])
    except BadHeaderError:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
else:
    # In reality we'd use a form class
    # to get proper validation errors.
    return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
```

these are my **contact.html**

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="/send_email/" >
{% csrf_token %}
Name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="username"><BR>
Email: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="from_email"><BR>
Message: <BR>
<TEXTAREA NAME="message" ROWS="10" WRAP="hard">
</TEXTAREA>
<INPUT NAME="redirect" TYPE="hidden">
<INPUT NAME="NEXT_URL" TYPE="hidden">
<BR>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Send">
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Clear">
</FORM>
```

these are my **URLS.PY**

```
url(r'^send_email/', views.send_email),
url(r'^contact/', views.contact),
url(r'^thanks/', views.thanks),
```

and my **SETTINGS.PY**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'localhost'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ''
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ''
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Comment: You need to return an instance of `RequestContext`. Use the [`render` shortcut](http://django.me) in place of your `HttpResponse`.

Comment: how sir?, can you please type the code for me?

Comment: still you are getting `csrf verification  faild` error ???

Comment: yes :( Reason given for failure:

    CSRF token missing or incorrect.

Comment: have you added `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` this to your list of middleware classes ??

Comment: yes, I added it already :)

Comment: every thing is fine so once clear all your browsing data or try with another browser may be works :)

Comment: go through [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/csrf/)

Comment: why you changed `POST` to `get`? and please use `GET` not `get` edit in form also

Comment: if you are using smtp  `EMAIL_PORT = 1025` and run this `python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025` command in another terminal

Answer (score 3):

Your `action` value of form must direct to view's url, `mailto:canonizadocharm@ymail.com` is not a valid path on your server.

**UPDATED**:

For example, add a new rule to urls.py like,

```
url(r'^mail/', views.send_mail),
```

Then change action value to `mail`.

Comment: how can i do that?, can you help me please? I am new in django :(

Comment: Add `{% csrf_token %}` to somewhere inside of form in contact.html.

Answer (score 0):

Have your action value point to a URL, which in turn points to one of your views. For instance, your urls.py can do this.

```
url(r'^email/', 'project.views.send_email')
```

This will route your contact form to your send_mail view.

Answer (score 0):

Your form in the templates has no csrf that's why you get an error of "CSRF verification failed".

```
 <FORM METHOD=POST ACTION="/send_email/" ENCTYPE="text/plain">{% csrf_token %}
 ...........
 </FORM>
```

If you want to know what is csrf just go to this link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

---

Create email setting in your settings.py, like this for example:

**settings.py**

```
# Sending mail
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='your gmail account'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='your gmail password'
```

**views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

def send_email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        from_email = request.POST.get('from_email')
        send_mail(username, message, from_email, ['canonizadocharm@ymail.com',])
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Make sure all fields are entered and valid.')
```

Comment: I forgot to tell you, did you put email setting in settings.py?

Comment: Yes for email setting like I did above for example

Comment: still it does not work :( 
I copy pasted all of your suggestions ma'am, and nothing happens.

Comment: Is the process ok now? What's the error now? Your taking IT course right from philippines?

Comment: Yes I'm currently taking IT course @ Philippines. It continue resulting the same error. "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted."

Comment: Magkababayan pala tayo eh, pwede bang makita 'yung lahat ng codes mo pra matrace ko ang dahilan?

Comment: Hahaha. OJT palang po kasi ako eh, nahihirapan po ako kasi bago ako sa django.. pano ko po papakita? :)

Comment: chamyui22 pa-add nalang po sa skype para masend ko ung files :)

Comment: sa gmail nalang, ayaw kung magskype :), catherinetenajeros@gmail.com

Comment: sge send ko nlng po yung , settings.py, views, urls, contact.html, thanks.html sa inyo

Comment: new error encountered. it only displays "Make sure all fields are entered and valid."

Comment: i updated my codes, it display error "[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it"

Comment: nasend ko na bago lang and it's working. And I also notice you name your view send_email which is not allow because django has a built-in function for that